Load FAISS embedding index file (.pkl and .faiss) from Google Cloud Storage Bucket to Cloud Function
I've trained FAISS locally from several documents and saved the embedding with ".save_local" function. The embedding files (.pkl and .faiss) are uploaded to the Google Cloud Storage Bucket.
Now I want to load the embedding with the langchain "FAISS.load_local" function. However, I didn't find any solutions to make the index file accessible by the "FAISS.load_local" function.
I've tried using blob with download_as_string, and download_to_file functions and making them available in the RAM path: "/tmp". I've checked in the directory and they saved with each format (.pkl and .faiss). Neither of them is accessible by the load function, the error is attached below, seems like the file is corrupted and it couldn't be searched within the load_local function especially tiktoken.
The error
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tiktoken/core.py", line 116, in encode
    if match := _special_token_regex(disallowed_special).search(text):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or buffer"

The blob code
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET)

EMBEDDINGS_PATH = '/tmp'
filepath = "embeddings"
filename = "index.faiss" or "index.pkl"

#I create a function to iterate the filename, and this is part of the function's code
blob_file = bucket.blob(blob_name="{}/{}".format(filepath,filename)) 
save_file = "{}/{}".format(EMBEDDINGS_PATH, filename)
downloaded_file = blob_file.download_as_string()
with open(save_file, "wb") as f:
      f.write(downloaded_file)

#load the embeddings file
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"])
vectorstore=FAISS.load_local(folder_path="EMBEDDINGS_PATH", embeddings=embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)


Hope anyone can share the correct way to access and load faiss embeddings from Google Cloud Storage Bucket to Cloud Function. Thank you
